# implement filter using static variable - novice

Tags: asp.net

I have an HTML textbox where a user types some text and then the entries matching the text are retrieved from the database. I store this filter string value in a static string variable because I need to use its value somewhere in the program.

the question is: will all users currently logged in end up with the same filter result and overwrite their own filters every time they do a change.

Comment: yes, static variable will hold the same value for all users

Comment: ok..thanks for the info

Comment: @Lashane what is the best way to implement this filter without using static variables ? cna you please tell me ?

Comment: pass this value into your search function